How to fix error "OPENSSL_Uplink(00007FF939F55C88,08): no OPENSSL_Applink" when trying to install a python package?
I am trying to install packages within a OSGEO4w(QGIS 3.36.2) shell, but it fails with OPENSSL_Uplink(00007FF939F55C88,08): no OPENSSL_Applink.  This is preventing me from installing any packages.  How do I fix this error?
Version information:
C:\OSGeo4W>pip --version
pip 24.0 from C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.12)

Here is an example:
C:\OSGeo4W>pip install D:\Apps\Python\pycellmech-2.1.8-py3-none-any.whl
Processing d:\apps\python\pycellmech-2.1.8-py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in c:\osgeo4w\apps\python312\lib\site-packages (from pycellmech==2.1.8) (3.8.4)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\osgeo4w\apps\python312\lib\site-packages (from pycellmech==2.1.8) (1.26.4)
OPENSSL_Uplink(00007FF939F55C88,08): no OPENSSL_Applink


Not sure if this might help.  https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/108687
